# My laptops wi-fi gets disconnects automatically

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, laptop

hi i have dell inspiron 3520 laptop,and for last two months i am having problem with my wi-fi connects.I connect wi-fi and when i start using internet it gets automatically disconnected so i every time i have to troubleshoot in network and sharing center.So it is hardware or software issue? Please help me out with this problem and also tell me which driver is needed to be installed from dell web site.I have also attache screenshot of the list of drivers available on dell website for my laptop.[Network drivers for Dell inspiron 3520](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvOpX.jpg)

Comment: Suspect your problem is the fact your running Windows 10 and those drivers do not specifically support Windows 10

Comment: @BramMooij - The provided screenshot, indicates Windows 10, hence my comment.

Comment: I recently had a similar issue (wifi card stopping, turning it off and on again temporarily solving the issue) and replacing the card solved it immediately. Therefore, a hardware problem is indeed possible. If you want to know which driver you'd need, please tell us which wifi card you have (it should say it here: o to Device manager -> network adapters->your adapter). Did you update to Windows 10 recently?

Comment: @ Ramhound, I missed that. I suspect you are right as well, as this is a comment I pulled from the Dell website: "Product not tested for Windows 10 upgrade

Dell is not testing or developing Windows 10 drivers for this product. If you choose to upgrade, some features, applications, and connected devices may not work as expected." However, perhaps the manufacturer of the WiFi card does support Windows 10, and the problem could be solved by installing the drivers directly from the manufacturer.

Answer (score 0):

**One possible solution** Go to Device manager -> network adapters->your adapter-> right-click the installed adapter->properties->driver, try rollback driver. This brings you back to an older driver situation (possibly one where you have no problems).

**One other possible solution**: the easiest way for me to decide whether something is a hardware or software issue is starting the computer with another operating system. If you go the Ubuntu website, you can easily find how to create an Ubuntu USB stick. You can boot directly from this USB stick (go into your startup device order menu when the laptop starts up, or go into the bios). This allows you to test your WiFi card under completely different software circumstances. If the WiFi card then continues to show similar behaviour, it is probably the card.

Comment: Hi Ramhound, you were right, I mixed some comments with the answer, I split the two. Now the comment part is in comments and the answer part remains here. Regardless of his operating or WiFi card, these are useful suggestions independent on the operating system (unless it's ubuntu of course).